# Can a third kind of charge exist?

Tags: electromagnetism, charge

Is it possible that apart from *positive* and *negative* charges, there is a third kind of charge that we have somehow, not discovered yet?

If not, is there some proof of the existence of only two types of charges?

Comment: How could we ever prove such thing? Just because we've never seen something like it, does not mean it can't exist.

Comment: Right, that's what I thought. But I also thought that maybe some "higher" field of Science deals with this kind of stuff (theoretical Physics, maybe). I wasn't sure, so I asked this here.

Comment: By the way, hypothetically, let's say that we find another type of charge someday. Which is more likely : the type of charge always existed but we never noticed that **or** it gets discovered under some "special" artificial conditions.

Comment: what properties do you think such a charge would have?

Comment: Not to forget color charges designed to describe the strong interactions http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Forces/color.html

Comment: I think the term charge is quite ambiguous here. It's not clear what OP has in mind

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/132654/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @TheoreticalMinimum I'm referring to electrical charges. Just like positive and negative charges...

Comment: @Rajdeep_Sindhu What porperties would it share with classical charges, what would be the differences? It's not as obvious as you make it sound.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we did discover some other phenomenon for which the description "charge" was appropriate, we would not call it an electrical charge. For example the gluons which bind an atomic nucleus together carry a triple-state charge which is called "colour charge" after the three primary colours of vision. The theory of electromagnetism is a complete and consistent description of certain natural phenomena. Anything coming outside that set of phenomena would come outside the theory of electromagnetism and we would not call it electrical charge.

Comment: I think I get it, partially. Thanks :)