# Why don't we have just one type of charge? Why do we need two?

Tags: electromagnetism, particle-physics, electricity, charge

Why do we need to admit two types of charges (positive and negative)? Can't there be a third type?

Comment: Hmm. But what would it be? What would be its properties?

Comment: @BobD Quantum chromodynamics (QCD), the theory of the strong nuclear force between quarks, has three kinds of “color charge”, usually referred to as red, blue, and green. Mathematically, it is analogous to electric charge but more complicated.

Comment: Your title does not fit the body of the question. You should change one of them.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/132654/2451 and links therein.

Comment: We need not only two charges, we also need the magnetic dipoles of these charges.

**Of course we don't need anything, we just get these qualities from nature.**

But if you study the phenomena of these properties you will see how beautiful they are interacting. Moving electrons through a magnetic field, we are able to separate these charges, translate them and get a use from this (generator -> current -> motor). Moving separated charges in a coil we get a common magnetic field, this, very helpful in electromagnets.

Comment: All the electronics is based on it. And at the end, all chemical and even all biologic processes are based on that.

Comment: In a sense, there *is* only one kind of electric charge. In terms of symmetry, positive & negative are like clockwise & anticlockwise rotation, mirror images of each other. The linked answers mention this U(1) symmetry group (but don't explain what it is, or exactly how it's connected with electricity).

Answer (score 4):

If you take a collection of materials (glass, amber, polythene, perspex, pvc, polystyrene....) and rub them with a soft insulating material, they acquire charges. You discover that all these rubbed materials can be put into just two categories. All those in one category repel each other and attract any of those in the other category. Two categories; two sorts of charge.

This is the gist of the original argument, dating back some three hundred years. Subsequent discoveries have given us no reason to challenge it. For example, electrons are repelled by suitably rubbed amber or polythene but attracted by glass or perspex and therefore fall into the negative charge category.

What is more, equal quantities of the two sorts of charge can be represented by $+R$ and $-R$ in which $R$ is a positive real number with unit. For example the force on charge $Q_2$ due to charge $Q_1$ is

$$\mathbf F=\frac{Q_1 Q_2}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 r^2} \mathbf {\hat r} $$

and if $Q_1$ is negative and $Q_2$ is positive, $\mathbf{F}$ is in the opposite direction to $\mathbf {\hat r}$, the unit vector in the $Q_1Q_2$ direction.

Comment: Would the down-voter please give a reason? We might all benefit.