# How do we know charge is only positive and negative?

Tags: electrons, charge, protons

Could there be a charge different than that of a proton and that of an electron? Could there be a third type of charge that is not repulsed or attracted by either an electron's charge or a proton's charge? Maybe it would, however, be attracted by an opposite third kind of charge?

Note: Quarks still possess same type of charge, just a fractional amount of it.

Comment: Does color charge count?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/132654/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 2):

Could there be some kind of charge other than positive & negative? In theory yes, but it's not experimentally observed. You could compare [color charge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_charge) to see what a theory with more than 2 charges would look like, so it's not like it cannot be observed, only that we have not seen it.

Comment: I am thinking that charge has a lot to do with how light propagates, right? and if so, the charge I am asking about would be maybe a different thing than light or another way for light to propagate?

Comment: No. Charge is what is conserved because of gauge invariance. In E&M, with a $U(1)$ gauge symmetry, you get 1 charge (electric charge) and 1 boson (the photon). In and $SU(N)$ gauge symmetry you get $N$ charges and $N^2-1$ gauge bosons, hence weak isospin and weak hypercharge with the $W^{\pm}, Z$ boson, while QCD has 3 color charges and 8 gluons.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The electromagnetic field is one component of the *electroweak force*, which applies at extremely high energies. At the much lower energies where we live, the Higgs mechanism hides the other parts so they only work at the very short ranges inside atoms, and leaves electromagnetism out on its own.

The 'charge' for the electroweak force has four components: the three components of the *weak isospin* ($T_1$, $T_2$, $T_3$), and one component called the *weak hypercharge* ($Y$). At high energies (far higher than the Large Hadron Collider can reach), they all correspond to long-range forces carried by four massless bosons. At lower energies, three bosons (called $W^+$, $W^-$, and $Z^0$) are given mass, and are unstable so they decay very quickly, which means the force cannot extend very far. These make up the *weak nuclear force*, and it is responsible for some kinds of radioactive decay. The other one stays massless, and is the photon. Electric charge is made up of a certain combination of weak isospin and weak hypercharge ($T_3+Y/2$), you can think of it as pointing in one particular direction in a four-dimensional charge space. The other three dimensions correspond to different sorts of 'charge', which are subject to the weak nuclear force.

There is also a 'charge' corresponding to the strong nuclear force, called *colour*, but again we don't see it in everyday life because it is incredible short range, and is usually confined to the insides of protons and neutrons. (It is what sticks the quarks together.)

And some people would say that *mass* is the 'charge' for the force of gravity. This is a bit unusual in that it is (almost) always positive, and like charges attract. But the analogy works to some extent.

Answer (score 1):

> Could there be a charge different than that of a proton and that of an electron?

Yes, e.g. [quarks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quark) have charge of either 2/3 or -1/3.

> Could there be a third type of charge that is not repulsed or attracted by either an electron's charge or a proton's charge?

[Neutron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutron) has charge of 0, thus it's neither repulsed nor attracted.

> Maybe it would, however, be attracted by an opposite third kind of charge?

Maybe, but not likely. We haven't observed anything like that.